# YA sci-fi book with a teen girl, an alien spaceship, and human experimentation

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I'm trying to find the title of a YA book that is about a teen girl whose boyfriend is taken by an alien. I think their spaceship is cloaked in a field near their school. The girl sneaks into the spaceship and finds out that aliens have been experimenting on people and the tests kill people. I don't think the book had a happy ending because the aliens still experiment on people and there was only one alien that helped out the girl, only because it wanted to learn more about Earth. I remember the alien calling Earth "blue planet" or something like that.

It's not a very thick book (around 200 pages). The cover of this book is light greenish and I think it has a field on it.

I think there are more books in this series, or there are more books similar to this one since it's a very quick read and the pages were white and not cream, I believe. I'm not sure when it was published, but I read this book in the early 2000s.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.se! Could you maybe also give a timeframe when you read the book -- or better yet, when it was published??

Comment: Rings a bell, but I can't quite place it.